# Simple Parse.com with findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock does not return

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am trying to query the _User Class from Parse to use it on a TableViewCell. I am getting a nil value from it. I did have it working at one time with a much simpler, but not recommended, query:

Working query (not recommended):

```
- (NSArray *)loadUsers {
PFQuery *users = [PFUser query];

return [users findObjects];}
```

Not working query:

```
- (void)loadAllUser:(void (^)(BOOL completion))completion {
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];

__block NSArray *loadUsers = [NSArray new];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        for (User *user in objects) {
            loadUsers = [loadUsers arrayByAddingObject:user];
        }
        [TaskController sharedInstance].loadAllUser = loadUsers;
    }else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

}

I am subclassing the _User Class from Parse (just FYI)

Comment: Please present evidence that the query doesn't work, for example, `NSLog(@"%@", objects) ` at the start of the completion block.  As a side note - there's no need for the __block variable, and its wasteful to use an immutable array with arrayByAddingObject:, but we can work on that separate from the query.

Comment: Please specify what variable is getting the nil value.  As @danh pointed out, we need to know exactly what is coming back in the objects array before continuing to troubleshoot the problem. Also, does the caller of loadAllUser need to know when the fetch is complete? If so, I don't see any place in loadAllUser that calls the completion block.

Comment: I have found the problem. The method was not getting called by the numberOfRowsInSection of the tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was when the method was called. The numberOfRowsInSection was not was passing a nil value.